# why image is not uploading through this php code

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

everything is working fine but photo is not uploading, please help

i am creating a system for storing data of computer training centers in php mysql . all code is working fine, but image upload is not working

i could not identify error ,

it seems

```php
$fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
that above part of code is not getting value from the form.
```

that above part of code is not getting value from the form.

```
<?php
include("php/dbconnect.php");
include("php/checklogin.php");
$errormsg = '';
$action = "add";

$branch='';
$address='';
$detail = '';
$id= '';
$image=PATHINFO($_FILES['image']['name']);
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{

$branch = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['branch']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['address']);
$detail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['detail']);

$newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'upload/' . $newFilename); 
$photo='upload/' . $newFilename.$image['name'].$image['extension'];

 if($_POST['action']=="add")
 {

  $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO branch (branch,address,detail,photo) VALUES ('$branch','$address','$detail','$photo')") ;

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="branch.php?act=1";</script>';

 }else
  if($_POST['action']=="update")
 {
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);   
   $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE  branch  SET  branch  = '$branch', address  = '$address', detail  = '$detail'  WHERE  id  = '$id'");
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="branch.php?act=2";</script>';
 }



}




if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="delete"){

$conn->query("UPDATE  branch set delete_status = '1'  WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
header("location: branch.php?act=3");

}


$action = "add";
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="edit" ){
$id = isset($_GET['id'])?mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id']):'';

$sqlEdit = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM branch WHERE id='".$id."'");
if($sqlEdit->num_rows)
{
$rowsEdit = $sqlEdit->fetch_assoc();
extract($rowsEdit);
$action = "update";
}else
{
$_GET['action']="";
}

}


if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && @$_REQUEST['act']=="1")
{
$errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success!</strong> Branch Add successfully</div>";
}else if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && @$_REQUEST['act']=="2")
{
$errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success!</strong> Branch Edit successfully</div>";
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && @$_REQUEST['act']=="3")
{
$errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success!</strong> Branch Delete successfully</div>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>School Fees Payment System</title>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!--CUSTOM BASIC STYLES-->
    <link href="css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--CUSTOM MAIN STYLES-->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

     <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>



</head>
<?php
include("php/header.php");
?>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div id="page-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1 class="page-head-line">Branch  
                        <?php
                        echo (isset($_GET['action']) && @$_GET['action']=="add" || @$_GET['action']=="edit")?
                        ' <a href="branch.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Back <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></a>':'<a href="branch.php?action=add" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add </a>';
                        ?>
                        </h1>

<?php

echo $errormsg;
?>
                    </div>
                </div>



        <?php 
         if(isset($_GET['action']) && @$_GET['action']=="add" || @$_GET['action']=="edit")
         {
        ?>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
               <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                           <?php echo ($action=="add")? "Add Branch": "Edit Branch"; ?>
                        </div>
                        <form action="branch.php" method="post" id="signupForm1" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-body">




                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Old">Branch </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="branch" name="branch" value="<?php echo $branch;?>"  />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Old">photo </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" value="<?php echo $image;?>"  />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Password"> Address </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address"><?php echo $address;?></textarea >
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Confirm"> Detail</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="detail" id="detail"><?php echo $detail;?></textarea >
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $action;?>">

                                    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>





                         </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                            </div>


                </div>




        <script type="text/javascript">


        $( document ).ready( function () {          

             if($("#signupForm1").length > 0)
         {
            $( "#signupForm1" ).validate( {
                rules: {
                    branch: "required",
                    address: "required"



                },
                messages: {
                    branch: "Please enter branch name",
                    address: "Please enter address"


                },
                errorElement: "em",
                errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
                    // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
                    error.addClass( "help-block" );

                    // Add `has-feedback` class to the parent div.form-group
                    // in order to add icons to inputs
                    element.parents( ".col-sm-10" ).addClass( "has-feedback" );

                    if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                        error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter( element );
                    }

                    // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                    if ( !element.next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                        $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( element );
                    }
                },
                success: function ( label, element ) {
                    // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                    if ( !$( element ).next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                        $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( $( element ) );
                    }
                },
                highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                    $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-10" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
                    $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-remove" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-ok" );
                },
                unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                    $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-10" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
                    $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-ok" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-remove" );
                }
            } );

            }

        } );
    </script>



        <?php
        }else{
        ?>

         <link href="css/datatable/datatable.css" rel="stylesheet" />




        <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Manage Branch  
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                             <div class="table-sorting table-responsive">

                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tSortable22">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Branch</th>
                                            <th>Address</th>
                                            <th>Detail</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $sql = "select * from branch where delete_status='0'";
                                    $q = $conn->query($sql);
                                    $i=1;
                                    while($r = $q->fetch_assoc())
                                    {
                                    echo '<tr>
                                            <td>'.$i.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$r['branch'].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$r['address'].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$r['detail'].'</td>
                                            <td>
                                            <a href="branch.php?action=edit&id='.$r['id'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>

                                            <a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this record\');" href="branch.php?action=delete&id='.$r['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> </td>
                                        </tr>';
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                    ?>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

    <script src="js/dataTable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#tSortable22').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true });

         });


    </script>

        <?php
        }
        ?>



            </div>
            <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
        </div>
        <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
    </div>
    <!-- /. WRAPPER  -->

    <div id="footer-sec">
    </div>


    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
       <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/custom1.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to printr_($_FILES) and post what it write on your page

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Should be like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="branch.php" method="post" id="signupForm1" class="form-horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

place the below code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="branch.php" method="post" id="signupForm1" class="form-horizontal">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this

`<form action="branch.php" method="post" id="signupForm1" class="form-horizontal">`

to this
 `<form action="branch.php" method="post" id="signupForm1" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">`